# Business Central Create pick document not working

Tags: dynamics-business-central, businesscentral

I am unable to create a warehouse pick document. I have created a sales order with a line item with location code **EAST**. The **Require pick** is enabled for this location.

Upon creating a warehouse shipment I see that the **Qty. to ship** is set to 0.

When I try to create a pick it says **Nothing to handle**.

I am creating a sales order. I want to create a pick document because the location (EAST) requires pick.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this question refers to a normal Business Central tenant without extensions, right?

> Upon creating a warehouse shipment I see that the Qty. to ship is set to 0.

This is correct. The *Qty. to ship* will be updated, once you create and register the required *Pick*.

> When I try to create a pick it says Nothing to handle.

This is most likely because the item you want to pick is not available at the specified location.

Make sure that you have the item in stock in this warehouse. You can do this, for example, by posting a *Purchase Order* or directly via *Item Journals*.